in linq'System.dateTime as DateTime(System.string) method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
DateTime todayDateTime = P.getCurrentDateTime();
pmap_attendence customername = db.pmap_attendence
    .Where(x => x.att_cust_guid.ToString() == input.cust_guid.ToString() 
        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.att_login_date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayDateTime))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.att_login_time)
    .FirstOrDefault();

i am unable to solve this issue , kindly help i am getting this error error

Linq to entities does not recognize the method 'System.dateTime as
DateTime(System.string) method and this method cannot be translated
into a store expression

This is the code that fails :
using kiakahawebandmvc.Logics;
using kiakahawebandmvc.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.WebPages;

namespace kiakahawebandmvc.Controllers.Backend
{
    public class CustomerAttendanceLoginController : ApiController
    {

        inlfflje_kiakahaEntities db = new inlfflje_kiakahaEntities();

        public class CustomerAttendanceLoginOutput
        {
            public Boolean is_success;
            public string msg;
        }

        public class CustomerAttendanceLoginInputs
        {
            public string cust_guid { set; get; }
            public string branch_guid { set; get; }
            public string login_date { set; get; }
            public string login_time { set; get; }
        }

        public CustomerAttendanceLoginOutput Post(CustomerAttendanceLoginInputs input)
        {

            CustomerAttendanceLoginOutput res = new CustomerAttendanceLoginOutput();
            res.is_success = false;
            res.msg = "Something went wrong";

            try {
                DateTime todayDateTime = P.getCurrentDateTime();
            pmap_attendence customername = db.pmap_attendence.Where(x => (x.att_cust_guid.ToString() == input.cust_guid.ToString()) && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.att_login_date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayDateTime))).OrderByDescending(x => x.att_login_time).FirstOrDefault();
            if (customername != null)
            {
                    if (customername.att_login_time > todayDateTime.AddMinutes(-45)) { 

                        res.is_success = false;
                        res.msg = "Customer Already Loggedin at " + customername.att_login_time + ", Try after sometime";
                        return res;
                    }
            }
                //Checking Booked class today date ----Added by Harish 03-08-2024

               //notworking //pmap_active_members_class_booking bookingdate = db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => (x.class_customer_guid.ToString() == input.cust_guid.ToString()) && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.class_booking_date.AsDateTime()) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayDateTime))).OrderByDescending(x => x.class_booking_date).FirstOrDefault();
              //pmap_active_members_class_booking bookingdate = db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => (x.class_customer_guid.ToString() == input.cust_guid.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
               pmap_active_members_class_booking bookingdate = db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => x.class_cl_guid == input.class_guid && x.booking_date == DateTime.Today && x.customer_guid == input.cust_guid).FirstOrDefault();
               if (bookingdate != null)
                {
                    //INSERTING INTO DATABASE
                    pmap_attendence a = new pmap_attendence();
                    a.att_guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    a.att_cust_guid = new Guid(input.cust_guid);
                    a.att_branch_guid = new Guid(input.branch_guid);
                    a.att_login_date = P.getCurrentDateTime();
                    
                    a.att_login_time = P.getCurrentDateTime();
                    a.att_login_time_only = P.RoundUp(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                    a.att_status = 1;
                    db.pmap_attendence.Add(a);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    db.V2CustomerUpdateRewardPoints(new Guid(input.cust_guid), 5);
                    res.is_success = true;
                    res.msg = "Successfully logged in";
                    return res;
                }
                else
                {
                    res.is_success = false;
                    res.msg = "You are not booking class today";

                    return res;
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                res.is_success = false;
                res.msg = "Error rohit " + e;

                return res;
            }

        }

    }
}


The question is unclear but the query is definitely wrong and would be slow even if it worked. DateTime has no constructor with a string. Dates and GUIDs aren't aren't strings, either in C# or the database. If login_date in the database is a date field, there's no need to truncate. DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayDateTime) is definitely wrong, it's asking the database to truncate the time part, something that can be done with just DateTime.Date. The fast way to search for rows in a date is to use x.att_login_date >=inputDate.Date ** x.att_login_date < inputDate.Date.AddDays(1)

What's the real error message? No .NET or EF library would include 'System.dateTime as DateTime(System.string) method. The type names are wrong - it's System.DateTime, not System.dateTime. Does the real error complain about DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.att_login_date), because there's no date at all but just a string? That call really makes no sense at all. You can't attempt time truncation in a string. Storing dates as strings is a major unfixable bug anyway, because you can never know what's stored in that string.

i understand but i tried many ways Please provide solution for this  code             pmap_active_members_class_booking bookingdate = db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => (x.class_customer_guid.ToString() == input.cust_guid.ToString()) && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.class_booking_date.AsDateTime()) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayDateTime))).OrderByDescending(x => x.class_booking_date).FirstOrDefault();

Please don't add code to comments as it's so difficult to read. Please take the time to read the comments above and update the question as requested. If you do this, we will have a better chance of being able to help you resolve your query.

you mean to change this  a.att_login_date = P.getCurrentDateTime(); to x.att_login_date >=inputDate.Date ** x.att_login_date < inputDate.Date.AddDays(1

Add the code in the question itself. We can't help when we have no idea what the classes are, what the tables look like or even whether class_booking_date is a date or a string. Adding more code won't fix anything - especially custom code like AsDateTime. class_booking_date should be a DateTime, stored in a datetime or datetime2 field in the database, not a string

please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78997754/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-asdatetimesystem

No, edit this question and add the missing information here. There's no AsDateTime in .NET and isn't even needed. Add the information we asked in this question

string login_date isn't a date and won't be treated as a date by LINQ. Change the property to DateTime. Remove AsDateTime entirely, along with using System.Web.WebPages;. ASP.NET Web Pages was a transitional technology introduced in 2002. If you use ApiController you're using Web API 2 at least.

The code contains a correct query 10 lines below the incorrect one. db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => x.class_cl_guid == input.class_guid && x.booking_date == DateTime.Today && x.customer_guid == input.cust_guid).FirstOrDefault(); Have you tried writing the new query like the old one? Something tells that booking_date is a DateTime

Please [edit] the question: remove all non-essential code, which probably means the entire second code block, and insert the class definition of pmap_attendence. That said, don't do date checks by truncating DateTime values. Check if they are between two date values (date and date + 1 day).

guys if i add below code i am getting this error ,kindly guide me step by step what changes i can make to solve this  db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => x.class_cl_guid == input.class_guid && x.booking_date == DateTime.Today && x.customer_guid == input.cust_guid).FirstOrDefault();

this is main error which i am not able to fix it properly (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.class_booking_date.AsDateTime()) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todayDateTime))).OrderByDescending(x => x.class_booking_date)

if i use this i am getting errors too db.pmap_active_members_class_booking.Where(x => x.class_cl_guid == input.class_guid && x.booking_date == DateTime.Today && x.customer_guid == input.cust_guid)

we can connect through gmeet

"if i use this i am getting errors too ..." but you don't tell us what errors you're getting and you haven't updated your question with all this necessary debugging information. By not editing/updating your question with this info it's very difficult to figure out what is going on. You haven't even taken the time to update the question with the actual error message.

i am trying to update code but its not taking it
